# Angular ng-class not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got the following HTML, and I'm trying to print a class using `ng-class` to the box, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

http://plnkr.co/edit/5KqnetMmq5DPe1Dm2ecc?p=preview

```
   <div ng-controller="myObject">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="updateClass()">{{ type ? 'One' : 'Two' }}</a>

        <div class="box" ng-class="{{ type ? 'one' : 'two' }}"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: get rid of the `{{ }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ng-class gets evaluated on it's own.  You don't need the {{}}

```
<div class="box" ng-class=" type ? 'one' : 'two' "></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-class` as an attribute :

```
ng-class="expression"
```

`ng-class` as css :

```
class="ng-class: expression;"
```

You don't need to write expression in ng-class
for more details you should go through [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)